# Android Library error

Tags: java, android, sbt-android-plugin

Hello so I built a android library to unity, and in the beggining it worked fine but know is giving me this error 
I already tried to update, create a new one, and nothing works 
Any help?

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHk4T.png)

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="sendtounityservice.sendintent.test.com.myapplication"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtlexporte="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver
            android:name="sendtounityservice.sendintent.test.com.myapplication.MyReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="sendtounityservice.sendintent.test.com.myapplication.IntentToUnity" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

first error in xmlns - URI is not registered (Settings | ..)

Answer (score 0):

Like the error states: "supportsRtlexporte" is not found.
You possibly meant "supportsRtl".